# Read file image data on client and resize it

Tags: image, html, canvas, resize, html5-canvas

I have gallery manager and drop area( for gallery image).
When files dropped. I use FileReader for read and get base64 data of image.
My goal is resize all images (make thumb/normal image) on client. 
Question: May i put base64 in to canvas then resize canvas and get new base64 of resized image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.getImageData({
  url: "http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3002/2758349058_ab6dc9cfdc_z.jpg?zz=1",
  success: function(image){

    // Set up the canvas
    var can = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
    var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

    // Set the canvas width and heigh to the same as the image
    $(can).attr('width', image.width);
    $(can).attr('height', image.height);

    // Draw the image on to the canvas
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);

    // Get the image data
    var image_data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0,  image.width, image.height);
    var image_data_array = image_data.data;


    // Write the image data to the canvas
    ctx.putImageData(image_data, 0, 0);

  },
  error: function(xhr, text_status){
    // Handle your error here
  }
});
```